# This behaviour may be Windows client OS specific; please look in the server logs or try a Linux client

Tags: java, java-8, docx, docx4j, file-conversion

I need to convert a file from to `docx` in to `pdf`(java 8), so so I do this:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage =
Docx4J.load(new java.io.File("file.docx"));
MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
            
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("docx4jProcessed.pdf"));
Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

The problem is when the `Docx4J.toPDF(..)` is claeed it throws this error:

> ```
> org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: This behaviour may be Windows client OS specific; please look in the server logs or try a Linux client
>   at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:753)
>   at docx4jProject.docx4jMain.main(docx4jMain.java:39)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9016 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   at
> ```

I don't know what is the problem in my code. Anyone can help me?

Comment: a docx file is a Windows Word file. it might need some windows interaction there, have you tried running it on a Windows machine?

Comment: my purpose is take all element in docx file and put in a new file pdf!

Comment: Yes, I understand your purpose. But, docx is a Windows related type.

Comment: @Stultuske Huh? I dont see how this is related. It sounds more like a config setup problem on that docx4j tool. And note that docx isnt "windows" only. It might be true that the compnent JoeB is using doesnt work on Linux, but that isnt necessarily a "docx windows" problem.

Comment: You can absolutely open .docx files on any system (e.g. with LibraOffice)

Comment: My recommendation would be to do a deep dive into the documentation for the tool you are using. Your code looks good, and that exception comes from "inside" the tool/library you are using.

Comment: the error message is clear: Connect to localhost:9016 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused. Check the port whether it is occupied or the server was not started

Comment: Perhaps related: https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/toc-updation-t2673.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running the now obsolete PDF Converter to do conversion that way (which was the default in certain older versions of docx4j).

For alternatives, please see https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/09/office-pptxxlsxdocx-to-pdf-to-in-docx4j-8-2-3/